# numpy savetxt out of order when redirecting sys.stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, numpy, stdout

I would like to use `numpy.savetxt` to write a numpy array, with the option of writing either to stdout, or as part of a file (by redirecting stdout). e.g. (in Python3)

```
import numpy as np
import sys

def output( a ):
    print( 'before np.savetxt' )
    np.savetxt( sys.stdout.buffer, a  )
    print( 'after np.savetxt' )

a = np.array( [ ( 1, 2, 3 ), ( 4, 5, 6 ) ] )

output( a )

with open( 'test', 'w' ) as file_out:
    sys.stdout = file_out
    output( a )
```

This writes (to stdout):

```
before np.savetxt
1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00
after np.savetxt
```

but the 'test' file contains these entries out of order:

```
> cat test
1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00
before np.savetxt
after np.savetxt
```

Is it possible to have these outputs in consistent order, or should I use a different approach to combine `numpy.savetxt` with other commands to write to the same file?

Comment: Just add `flush=True` to the first `print` to make sure it flushes to the underlying buffer beforehand, or call `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Comment: You can also just [disable all buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/181654/6055997) on stdout.

Answer (score 2):

You can use inside your `output()` function only the `savetxt` command, passing the `header` and `footer` arguments:

```
def output( a ):
    header = 'before np.savetxt'
    footer = 'after np.savetxt'
    np.savetxt(sys.stdout.buffer, a, header=header, footer=footer)
```

As well reminded by @DavidParks,  it should be `sys.stdout` for Python 2.7 and `sys.stdout.buffer` for Python 3.x.

Comment: `sys.stdout` for python 2.7, `sys.stdout.buffer` for 3.x

Comment: @DavidParks, thanks I've edited the answer adding your remarks